# Is $f(x)=x^3$ injective, surjective, bijective, or none?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is $f(x)=x^3$ (x cubed) injective, surjective, bijective, or none? and why.

Thanks

Comment: what has been tried ? do you know the definitions of these terms ? that may help people answering.

Comment: When you write out the definitions the problem turns out not hard at all. Would be nice if you could show as some attempts, or some context so we can provide answers suited to your mathematical knowledge.

Comment: @kingW3 it also depends on what set you are considering ...

Comment: Depends on the domain and codomain under consideration.

Comment: Injective is where there are more x values than y values and not every y value has an x value but every x value has one y value. Surjective is where there are more x values than y values and some y values have two x values. Bijective is where there is one x value for every y value.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, the domain and codomain are important here. I will assume that $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, since this seems natural.

Take $x,y\in\Bbb R$, then to show injectivity, we need to show that: if $f(x)=f(y)$ then we have $x=y$. Can you show that $x^3=y^3\implies x=y$?

Take $y\in\Bbb R$, then to show surjectivity, we need to show that: there exists some $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $y=f(x)$. Can you show that $\forall y\in\Bbb R\exists x\in\Bbb R:y=x^3$?

Then bijectivity is true only when both injectivity and surjectivity are true.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that is increasing, because $f'(x)\geq 0$, and then,any restriction of $f$ is injective, and, inparticular, $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is bijective.

Comment: In general it is not sufficient that $f'(x)\geq 0$ to conclude that the function is injective. If the function is constant ($f'(x) = 0$) in an interval, for example, then the function will not be injective.

Comment: but its not the case, because there are not intervals where $f'=0$.

Comment: You don't need calculus to answer this question. Even with calculus done correctly, you haven't shown that the function is surjective. Just increasing isn't enough.